# android images in custom notification views inverse in dark mode (android 10.0)

Tags: android-notifications, android-darkmode

1. when i use systemPic style，use system xml,it works well.

```
        builder.setContentTitle(StringUtil.f(title));
        builder.setContentText(StringUtil.f(desc));

        if (poster != null) {
            builder.setLargeIcon(poster);
        }
        Notification notification = builder.build();
```

2. but when i use custom layout, the image in notification like a negative image:
   [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TTaw.png) vs [Invert image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yZY9.png)

Comment: Did you find anything related to this?

Comment: I am also facing this issue.